# Message Bar called from script shows in its own little window

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5

I'm trying to show a message bar in the main window, reporting on the result of a processing script. However, an empty message bar appears in the main window, and the text appears in a small little separate window, as below:

[image: error screenshot]

With a different message level (Warning) the blank message bar and the new window change their colour and icon accordingly:

[image]

But I prefer a normal message bar, all in one piece/place.

Anyone know what is missing here?

I am using `iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Title","Message text")` and have already imported:

`from qgis.utils import iface`

`from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar, QgisInterface`

I have tried changing to `QgisInterface.messageBar().pushMessage()` with the same results, and have also tried importing some Qt modules just in case, but with no effect:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import (
    QSizePolicy,
    QPushButton,
    QDialog,
    QGridLayout,
    QDialogButtonBox)
```

The message bar works as expected when run from the Python console....

Here is a MWA (adapted from the normal processing script template):

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar, QgisInterface
from qgis.utils import iface

class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'myscript'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('My Script')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'examplescripts'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

        # We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
        ))

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )

        if source is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))

        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPUT,
            context,
            source.fields(),
            source.wkbType(),
            source.sourceCrs()
        )

        # Send some information to the user
        feedback.pushInfo(f'CRS is {source.sourceCrs().authid()}')

        if sink is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSinkError(parameters, self.OUTPUT))

        total = 100.0 / source.featureCount() if source.featureCount() else 0
        features = source.getFeatures()

        for current, feature in enumerate(features):
            # Stop the algorithm if cancel button has been clicked
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                break

            # Add a feature in the sink
            sink.addFeature(feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

            # Update the progress bar
            feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))

        if False:
            buffered_layer = processing.run("native:buffer", {
                'INPUT': dest_id,
                'DISTANCE': 1.5,
                'SEGMENTS': 5,
                'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
                'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
                'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
                'DISSOLVE': False,
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
            }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']

        iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Title","Message text")
        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```

- The little window closes if you close the message bar, and vice versa.
- It happens when run from a saved script in the processing toolbox, and when running from the script editor.
- It still happens with only QGIS window open.

Comment: It's probably a wonder that your QGIS is not crashing. Your problem is explained [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#flags), because `iface.messageBar().pushMessage()` is a non thread safe api call. I suggest that you use the [QgsProcessingFeedback](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingFeedback.html) class as described [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#communicating-with-the-user) or implement the `flags()` method and return `QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading`.

Comment: `QgsMessageBar`

Comment: @Taras `QgsMessageBar`
@BenW thanks. The problem is completely solved by not threading the algorithm. Only drawback is that the main window is frozen while the algorithm runs.. 
Is there a way to show the messageBar in the algorithm's Parameter/Log window?
The reason I prefer messageBar instead of processing feedback, is that the messageBar is more "user-friendly" than the logs.

Comment: Or is it possible to trigger `iface.messageBar().pushMessage()` in the main thread or in the console, after the algorithm thread has finished?

Comment: After the algorithm has finished you can use `postProcessAlgorithm()` method, which is called from the main thread.